# C# - Call a Function from other script

Tags: c#, function

Hi everyone i wrote a SoketServer with C# 2005 Express for my explication  and its work fine .

when i revise a message in Soket.cs script , i realize it and call this function in mainform.cs .

```
public void AdverFilter(string value)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Adver"+value);
      this.adverBindingSource.Filter = "store_index Like '*" + value + "*'";
      //MessageBox.Show(this.adverBindingSource.Filter);
    }
```

message box show true filter value but adverbindingsourse dont filter my table...

Note : i create button and wrote this code and click it after AdverFilter function start but its show non value for adver filter...

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(this.adverBindingSource.Filter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `SupportsFiltering` property to see if the `BindingSource` can actually do filtering.

Comment: yeh , when i wrote a filter in textbox_textchange or button click events its work , but when i call it from a function its dont work

Comment: @user584110: Is the function called from a different thread? If so, you have cross threading issue.

Comment: ohumm ,i use thread in soket.cs i call my function from this file , but mainForm is normal ,how can i fix it ?

Comment: @user584110: You will need to `Invoke` the function in that case.